# Typescript: How can I refer to an anonymous type that is a child of a named type?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I am using [apollo-codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen) to generate TypeScript types from the GraphQL queries embedded in the tsx files in my project. An example of a generated type is:

```
export type MooQuery = {
  wines:  {
    edges:  Array< {
      node:  {
        nodeId: string,
        wineName: string | null,
        wineryId: number | null,
        vintageId: number | null,
        uomId: number | null
      },
    } | null > | null,
  } | null,
};
```

I would be passing the "nodes" to a helper method that renders a React component for each node. I'd like to do something like:

```
renderHelper(node: MooQuery.wines.edges.node) { // this won't work

}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Does what I want even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bracket notation

```
renderHelper(node: MooQuery['wines']['edges'][0]['node']) { // this should work
  //                                         ^^^ Don't forget the 0 for the array
}
```

Although in your case I'd just edit the type (You generate it only once for starting out, I hope?)

```
export type MooQuery = {
  wines:  {
    edges:  Array<{node: MooNode} | null > | null,
  } | null,
};

export type MooNode = {
    nodeId: string,
    wineName: string | null,
    wineryId: number | null,
    vintageId: number | null,
    uomId: number | null
}
```

Then just `MooNode`

Comment: This looks great, thanks! But I get a pretty strange error: `error TS2339: Property 'edges' does not exist on type '{ edges: ({ node: { nodeId: string; wineName: string | null; wineryId: number | null; vintageId: ...'.` - Looks contradictory to me?!

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I suggest you open a new question and link to this one.